# Displaying Data from SQL to vb.net textbox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to retrieve data from sql server to vb.net textbox but i don't know what else to do all the tutorials i have are just to retrieve records from the database to datagrid view..please help..

```
Private Sub txtrfid_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtrfid.KeyPress
    cn.Open()

    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE RFID like '%" & txtrfid.Text & "%'"
    End With
    MsgBox("Record Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")

    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    cn.Close()


    txtname.Text = 'Firstname'
```

Comment: You want to display only one name at a time (`txtrfid_KeyPress`) ??

Comment: @ WingedPanther - it worked but when i try other id numbers it only shows the first data. It should show the id that is equal to what i search

Comment: what's the _data type_ field `RFID` in your table ?? and you shouldn't use `RFID  like '%" & txtrfid.Text & "%'`, its better to use `RFID =" & txtrfid.Text & "`

Comment: the data type of RFID is varchar, it should also function like a search label but it only returns the same info even if i enter diff id number.

Comment: when i use RFID =" & txtrfid.Text & " i get an error.

Comment: Use `RFID ='" & txtrfid.Text & "'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're populating a `DataTable` with the data from the database so you then have to get the data from that `DataTable` into the `TextBox`.  You can do that with data binding, which is how you've probably seen it done with a grid, e.g.

```
txtname.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "Firstname")
```

That's definitely how you'd do it if you were retrieving multiple records that you wanted to be able to navigate, although you'd probably use a `BindingSource` in between.  If there's only one record then you might instead just move the data manually, e.g.

```
txtname.Text = CStr(dt.Rows(0)("Firstname"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display only a single value (`FirstName`) from Table then see following piece of code

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection("connstr")
      conn.Open()
      Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("", conn)
      Dim txtName As String
      cmd.CommandText = "SELECT firstname FROM Students WHERE RFID ='" & txtrfid.Text & "'"
      txtName = IIf(IsDBNull(cmd.ExecuteScalar), "", cmd.ExecuteScalar)
      If txtName <> "" Then
         MsgBox("Record Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")
         Textbox1.Text = ""
         Textbox1.Text = txtName
      else
         MsgBox("No Record Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "INFO.")
      End If
 End Using
```

Comment: tnx!, now it's fix, i also cannot display the other info before because the textbox is not cleared for the next input of id number i just put Textbox1.Clear() and it work well tnx.

Comment: sorry i didn't notice the checkmark because i have slow internet connection. but tnx anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to retrieve the data. You can simply retrieve the data from sql database to textbox using sql data reader which is one of my favourite. Let me share to you.
Note : Don't forget to import system.data.sqlclient

```
Private Sub txtrfid_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtrfid.KeyPress
        strConn = "Data Source=" & servernamehere & ";Initial Catalog=" & databasenamehere & ";User ID=" & userid & ";Password=" & password
        sqlConn = New SqlConnection(strConn)
        sqlConn.Open()
        Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("Your query here", sqlConn)
        Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
        myreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
        myreader.Read()
        If myreader.HasRows Then
            txtrfid.Text = myreader.Item("column name from sql database table").Tostring
        End If
        sqlConn.Close()
End Sub
```

You may catch the exception with Try-Catch Technique.

Comment: @AlistaireTurno  you got several good answers. if the problem is fixed, you should click the checkmark next to the best answer so this gets moved off the unanswered list.